# what does the dollar do on $height of a UITextfield object?

Tags: ios, dollar-sign

I just got aware that there are some properties on objects of classes that have a dollar sign as prefix:

```
$height
$left
$origin
$size
```

... etc

I can use it as a setter e.g.

```
self.textField.$height = 44;
```

Q: how is this called, what is it good for and is it good practice to use is like this?

Comment: probably you're using some custom library in your code?

Comment: Of course, thanks to rokjarc I'm now aware it comes from there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using category [UIView+FrameAdditions.h](https://gist.github.com/nfarina/3412730).

More on [categories here](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/03/27/objective-c-lesson-8-categories/).

$ signs have no special meaning in this case - they are actually a bit unconventional to use in ObjC.

It is just a way developer named the helper methods in this category.

This $-prefix looks a bit strange but on the other hand it does help distinguish between native ObjC properties of `UIView`'s frame and category helper methods.

Nick Farina (developer of this category) actually calls this as  "*kind of like jQuery for UIViews*"

As for your question: is it a good practice to use it like this?

As said: $-sign is uncommon and i would ditch it personally. Especially if there is a chance that someone else will once work on the same project.

But the category itself can be very usefull and time-saving.

Comment: Thanks, good answer! Never thought I would come along with $vars in Objc ;-)

Comment: No problem! Yes, those $ are so strange that i immediately remembered where i saw them. :)